# Python: Join two DataFrames with same column prefix on same indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, hierarchy

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "A_price": [10, 12],
    "B_price": [20, 21],
},
index = ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2021']
)
df1:
            A_price B_price
01-01-2020  10      20
01-02-2021  12      21

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "A_weight": [0.1, 0.12],
    "B_weight": [0.2, 0.21],
},
index = ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2021']
)
df2:
            A_weight B_weight
01-01-2020  0.1      0.2
01-02-2021  0.12     0.21
```

How can I join the two dataframes on the same indices and then have the columns in a hierarchy? i.e. I want the following:

```
df:
            A              B
            price weight   price weight      
01-01-2020  10    0.1      20    0.2
01-02-2021  12    0.12     21    0.21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` (or `merge`) and explode your column names.

```
# out = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
out = out.join(df2)
out.columns = out.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
out = out.sort_index(axis=1)
print(out)

# Output:
               A            B       
           price weight price weight
01-01-2020    10   0.10    20   0.20
01-02-2021    12   0.12    21   0.21
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply concat horizontally with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1`, and split the columns by `_` with [`.columns.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html) (which, with `expand=True`, returns a `MultiIndex`):

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
               A     B      A      B
           price price weight weight
01-01-2020    10    20   0.10   0.20
01-02-2021    12    21   0.12   0.21
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
pd.concat((df1.T,df2.T), keys=["A", "B"]).T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.concat` using the `keys` parameter with `sort_index()` to get them in the right structure. Then `rename` the columns to remove the prefix in the inner level of the multiindex:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['A','B'],axis=1).sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[1], level=1)

               A      B     A      B
           price weight price weight
01-01-2020    10   0.10    20   0.20
01-02-2021    12   0.12    21   0.21
```